# Why the UITableViewCell's changing their value in single cell?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

In my app, i have customize UITableViewCell and is using its contentView property. 
But now the problem is the data in cells are sometimes going in different cells. For example:The data in cell 3 is going into cell 8 or 9 when scroll to the bottom or scroll up.
Here's the code which iam using in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CGFloat fontSize = [UIFont systemFontSize];
    CGFloat smallFontSize = [UIFont smallSystemFontSize];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];
        mainLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,0,150,42)] autorelease];
        mainLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:smallFontSize];
        mainLabel.numberOfLines = 3;
        mainLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        mainLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        mainLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:mainLabel];

        secondLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160,0,160,42)] autorelease];
        secondLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:smallFontSize];
        secondLabel.numberOfLines = 3;
        secondLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        secondLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        secondLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:secondLabel];


    }
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:smallFontSize];
    cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:smallFontSize];
    NSArray * titles = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Project ID", @"Status", @"Approval Date", @"Closing Date", @"Country",@"Region Name", @"Env", @"Team Full Name",@"Borrower", @"Impagency", @"Lending Cost", @"IBRDPlus", nil];

    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:

            mainLabel.text = [titles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            mainLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
            mainLabel.numberOfLines = 4;
            mainLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;

            secondLabel.text = [self.basic objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            secondLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
            secondLabel.numberOfLines = 4;
            secondLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
            break;
        case 1:

            mainLabel.text = [[self.allSectors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"SECTORNAME"];
            mainLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
            mainLabel.numberOfLines = 4;
            mainLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;

            secondLabel.text = [[self.allSectors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"SECTORPCT"];
            secondLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
            secondLabel.numberOfLines = 4;
            secondLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;

            break;
        case 2:

            mainLabel.text = [[self.themes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"THEME_NAME"];
            mainLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
            mainLabel.numberOfLines = 4;
            mainLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;

            secondLabel.text = [[self.themes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"THEMEPCT"];
            secondLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
            secondLabel.numberOfLines = 4;
            secondLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;

            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: See my updated answer, that should fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because of this line (which you need to have anyway) :

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

Basically because the cells are being reused the content stays in the cell, therefore you need to clean that cell after dequeu and then set the new contentView.

What is happen here specifically is that even though you are resetting the text of `secondLabel`, when you are setting your variable here:

```
secondLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160,0,160,42)] autorelease];
```

The last cell that was created is what secondLabel is pointing to all the time, so you are really always changing the same label, therefore I would suggest something like this:

```
UILabel *lblCell;
for (id label in [cell.contentView subviews]) {
            if ([label isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
                lblCell = label;
            }
        }

lblCell.text = [[self.themes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"THEMEPCT"];
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I don't understand this exactly. If you can please elaborate more where exactly i need to use this loop and with what do i need to replace lblCell.

Comment: @Ashutosh the loop is just to get a pointer to the dequed cell contentView label so you can modify it, you would need to do this everytime you are changing the text in your label.

Comment: I still don't get where to put this. My pretty new and this is first time i am customizing cells. So that would be great of you can just edit in my code that will hep me understand it correctly.

Comment: @Ashutosh in your switch statement, for each case instead of using second label before setting anything copy and paste my code there and replace secondlabel with lblcell, i would edit it but i am on my iphine atm so it is a little tricky. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much...i figured it out. It's working smoothly.